# toggling checkboxes using jquery with sql update and without a postback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, sql, vb.net

Background info: I'm using visual studio 2012, sql2008 db, asp.net and vb.net.

I've got a page that has 2 sections of data.  Under each gridview is a checkbox that says (basically) "make this data visible."  The two tables are similar data, and mutually exclusive, meaning, if they check one box, then the other option is off, and vice versa.  Also, when one is checked (or unchecked) then there is an sql UPDATE which is executed in the "CheckChanged" event.  Right now I have it running with autopostback and enabledViewState on both checkboxes set to true, and then the code just adjusts the other box accordingly, and fires off the sql.

My question is, is there any way to do this without a postback? I'm pretty new to javascript and jquery, and while I'm sure I could track down a way to toggle the two checkboxes off each other, I'd still have to run the sql, which, as far as I understand it, can't happen without a postback?

Comment: _"I'd still have to run the sql, which, as far as I understand it, can't happen without a postback?"_ - You can [make a request via Ajax](http://www.jquery-tutorial.net/ajax/introduction/) and get the response back directly to your JavaScript without reloading the page. You don't _need_ jQuery for this (or for anything), but I recommend it because it certainly makes things a lot easier - in your case perhaps the `$.post()` method would be the one to use.

Comment: Thanks.  Didn't even know client-side scripting could do this kind of thing.  Great new direction; thanks for the tip and the link!

Comment: You're welcome. The page I linked to isn't the greatest Ajax tutorial around, but it was the first one I found at the time and at least now you know what you're looking for. Although I definitely recommend jQuery I'd also recommend reading a plain JavaScript Ajax tutorial too so that you have a sense of what jQuery is doing for you behind the scenes.